# Making a SOAP REQUEST in PHP

Tags: php, soap, nusoap

I am trying to pass my `AgentCode`, `AgentUser`, `AgentPasswd` and `AgentSignature` variables with my code. Please help as I am new to SOAP.

This is the XML structure.

```
<soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <urn:GetLocationsList soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
         <HeaderInfo xsi:type="urn:THeaderInfo" xmlns:urn="urn:testsrvIntf">
            <AgentCode xsi:type="xsd:string">xxxx</AgentCode>
            <AgentUser xsi:type="xsd:string">xxxx</AgentUser>
            <AgentPasswd xsi:type="xsd:string">xxxx</AgentPasswd>
            <AgentSignature xsi:type="xsd:string">xxxx</AgentSignature>
         </HeaderInfo>
      </urn:GetLocationsList>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

And this is my PHP code:

```
require_once('lib/nusoap.php');
$wsdl = "http://webservices.xxxxxx.xxxxx";

$client = new nusoap_client($wsdl);
$parameters= array('HeaderInfo' => array('AgentCode'      => 'xxxx',
                                              'AgentUser'      => 'xxxx',
                                              'AgentPasswd'    => 'xxxx',
                                              'AgentSignature' => 'xxxx'));
$value = $client->GetLocationsList($parameters);

echo '<h2>Request</h2><pre>' . htmlspecialchars($client->request, ENT_QUOTES) . '</pre>';
echo '<h2>Response</h2><pre>' . htmlspecialchars($client->response, ENT_QUOTES) . '</pre>';
echo '<h2>Debug</h2><pre>' . htmlspecialchars($client->debug_str, ENT_QUOTES) . '</pre>';
```

Comment: what's the problem?

Comment: I've never used that library but is that the correct way to set authentication? is it not `$client->setCredentials(..)` ?

Comment: i am very confused how to pass  request with authentication.

Comment: i get this error:
PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method nusoap_client::GetLocationsList()

Comment: could someone tell me how should i make this request :

Comment: ...The manual of  this service (wsdl)  gives me only this information. TLocationsList 
 -  GetLocationsList(THeaderInfo HeaderInfo)

Comment: require_once('/lib/nusoap.php');
    $client = new nusoap_client("http://webservices.forth-crs.gr/ferriesWS-1.1.1/FcrsFerriesWS.dll/wsdl/IFcrsFerriesWS", array("trace"=>1, "exceptions"=>0));
    $parameters= array('AgentCode'      => 'xxxxx',
                       'AgentUser'      => 'xxxxx',
                       'AgentPasswd'    => 'xxxxx',
                       'AgentSignature' => 'xxxxx');

     $value = $client->GetLocationsList('THeaderInfo', $parameters);

Comment: i get error :
Fatal error: Call to undefined method nusoap_client::GetLocationsList() ........ on line 9

Answer (score 0):

You need to read the documentation for the nusoap library, if you're going to use it.

https://github.com/econea/nusoap

It looks like the correct way to make a call is:

```
$result = $client->call($action, $data);
```

The way you're doing is how the PHP SOAP client works.

http://php.net/manual/en/class.soapclient.php